# Download 2 Excell File from Laravel with One Button Click?

Tags: javascript, laravel, download, maatwebsite-excel

Routes :

```
Route::get('/exportPurchasing', 'SummaryController@exportPurchasing')->name('exportPurchasing');
```

Controller :

```
    public function exportPurchasing(Request $request)
    {
      return [
      Excel::download(new exportRekapPurchasing, 'RekapPurchasing.xlsx'),
      Excel::download(new exportChecklistWH, 'RekapChecklistWH.xlsx')
      ];
    }
```

Blade :

```
<form method="get" action="{{ route('exportPurchasing') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="input-group">
               <input type="text" name="date" class="form-control datepicker" autocomplete="off" value="">
               <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-download"></i> Rekap Purchasing and Checklis WH</button>
               </div>
          </div>
      </form>
```

When I click the button, I want to get to export data? I Used maatwebsite excel

Comment: then put them in the same method in the controller, get the files and compress them in a single file then send it to be downloaded

Comment: i didnt understand whats your problem is?

Comment: @Abilogos i just want to get two export data using one button

Comment: you mean by a zip file?

Comment: no in excel @Abilogos

Comment: 2 seperate excel?

Comment: @Abilogos yes in one

Comment: i cant help you with appending two excel files into each others. but maybe i have a solution to download two files with one button click

Comment: so, can you help me to download two files with one button click  ? @Abilogos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just try this on your button:

```
                    <button type="submit" onclick="downloadTwo()" class="btn btn-primary">
```

Rekap Purchasing and Checklis WH

and define JS fucntion as follow:

```
    function downloadTwo(){
     //jquery selection can be achieve via vanilla JS
     let dateVal = $("[name='date']").val();
window.open("{{route('exportPurchasing')}}?data=purcache&date="+dateVal,"_blank");
window.open("{{route('exportPurchasing')}}?data=checklist&date="+dateVal,"_blank");

    return false;
}
```

and in controller :

```
    public function exportPurchasing(Request $request)
        {
          switch($request->data){
          
          case "purcache":
               return Excel::download(new exportRekapPurchasing, 'RekapPurchasing.xlsx');

          case "checklist":
              return Excel::download(new exportChecklistWH, 'RekapChecklistWH.xlsx');

          default :
              return null;
          }
        }
```

Comment: i have edited and added your date input, check it out